# Debugging nodejs with webstorm

Tags: node.js, debugging, webstorm

I am learning nodejs and trying debug simple example.

```
var a = 1;
var b = 2;
var d = function(){
    return a + b;
}
console.log(d());
```

I put breakpoint were declared var a. But cant debug because buttons are grey. My webstorm configurations  http://imgur.com/a/NQOIM . Is it possible go step by step throught my program as in visual studio code?

Comment: Everything looks normal. The only grey buttons belong to the event log, which is irrelevant to the debugger..

Comment: Then I want ask can I go throught my program step by step as in Visual Studio Code program?